# Do dynamic libraries break C++ standard?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, language-lawyer

The C++ standard **3.6.3** states

**Destructors for initialized objects of static duration are called as a result of returning from main and as a result of calling exit**

On windows you have **FreeLibrary** and linux you have **dlclose** to unload a dynamically linked library.  And you can call these functions before returning from main.

A side effect of unloading a shared library is that all destructors for static objects defined in the library are run.

**Does this mean it violates the C++ standard as these destructors have been run prematurely ?**

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't say anything about libraries. Its scope is only a single program. The shared library itself is thus outside the scope of the standard, as is anything you do with it and to it.

Comment: It's like teenage sex.  Everybody wants to do it, nobody knows how, happens every day anyway.  You're not supposed to talk about it.

Comment: I don't know what else you hope to get out of this.  Runtime linked libraries are not a part of standard C++.  Neither is my recipe for roasted salsa, but you won't find an authoritative source saying so.

Comment: No one ha actually answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are only run prematurely if you go to great effort to do so - the default behavior is standard conforming.

Comment: How can you `dlclose` an object you haven't `dlopen`ed yourself?

Comment: @curiousguy, I don't know and that was my whole point. If you let the OS and C++ runtime load the dynamic libraries automatically and unload them at exit, everything just works.

Comment: That isn't how I understood the original question: I thought he wanted to know what happens when he `dlclose` an object that he has `dlopen`ed.

Comment: @curiousguy, C++ provides many different ways to shoot yourself in the foot. This one is pretty far down the list. The question made it clear what the expected behavior was when you unload a dynamic library explicitly, and in fact I don't disagree.

Comment: Yes, the expected behaviour is clear. The question was: "what happens from the standard point of view", and the answer is "the standard doesn't have a point of view on this".

Answer (score 23):

It's a meaningless question. The C++ standard doesn't say what `dlclose` does or should do.

If the standard were to include a specification for `dlclose`, it would certainly point out that `dlclose` is an exception to 3.6.3. So then 3.6.3 wouldn't be violated because it would be a documented exception. But we can't know that, since it doesn't cover it.

What effect `dlclose` has on the guarantees in the C++ standard is simply outside the scope of that standard. Nothing `dlclose` can do can violate the C++ standard because the standard says nothing about it.

(If this were to happen without the program doing anything specific to invoke it, then you would have a reasonable argument that the standard is being violated.)

Comment: Yes it does. The standard explicity states that static destructors not be run before main and dlclose does it . Does it not ?

Comment: That's not how standards work. Standards say what happens, but they never foreclose the possibility that you can explicitly request different behavior. If you get different behavior because you explicitly requested it, the standard is not violated. It is not required that every exception to a rule be stated with that rule. It is perfectly acceptable and routine for the exception to the rule to be stated in the documentation for the function that creates the exception -- `dlclose` in this case.

Comment: That is precisely my question, How can the very implementation of dlclose/FreeLibrary be violating the C++ standard ?

Comment: As I explained, it's not violating the C++ standard. The C++ standard doesn't say anything about what `dlclose` does or doesn't do. *Nothing* `dlclose` did could possibly violate the C++ standard. If it wanted to, `dlclose` could make `(1==2)` evaluate to true. That wouldn't violate the C++ standard because the C++ standard doesn't say what `dlclose` should do. Standards have a scope and say *nothing* about things outside their scope.

Comment: If the standard explicitly states 2 + 2 = 4. And somehow after calling dlclose 2 + 2 started coming out as 5. It should be violating the C++ standard.. NO ??? Even though standard doesn't explicitly state anything about dlclose.  We are not talking about function dlclose some Average Joe implemented. But shared library implementations in major desktop OSes

Comment: No, that wouldn't be violating the C++ standard. The C++ standard doesn't say what `dlclose` does or should do. It's simply outside the scope. So long as it happened only to code that called `dlclose`, the standard would be not be violated. It is critical to understand that standards have a very specific scope and don't constrain any behavior outside their scope.

Comment: The standard specifies that the destructors shall be run, when you return from main or call exit. Nothing more. It does not specify, that these are the *only* situations, where the destructors may be run. It is just a sufficient condition, but not a necessary one.

Comment: @ollb "_It does not specify, that these are the only situations, where the destructors may be run._" Nonsense.

Comment: @curiousguy If a standard says "X", that means X has to happen unless you ask otherwise. It doesn't prohibit an implementation from giving you an implementation-specific way to ask for X not to happen. Otherwise, every platform would violate pretty much every standard just because it gives you a power button.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "_unless you ask otherwise_" Right, that's the key point. When you explicitly ask for destruction, the usual destruction rules don't apply.

Comment: @curiousguy Exactly. Calling `dlclose` explicitly asks for the library to be closed. It is specifically documented to do this. "If the reference count drops to zero and no other loaded libraries use symbols in it, then the dynamic library is unloaded."

Answer (score 19):

Parapura, it may be helpful to keep in mind that the C++ standard is a language definition that imposes constraints on how the compiler converts source code into object code.

The standard does not impose constraints on the operating system, hardware, or anything else.

If a user powers off his machine, is that a violation of the C++ standard? Of course not. Does the standard need to say "unless the user powers off the device" as an "exception" to every rule? That would be silly.

Similarly, if an operating system kills a process or forces the freeing of some system resources, or even allows a third party program to clobber your data structures -- this is not a violation of the C++ standard. It may well be a bug in the OS, but the C++ language definition remains intact.

The standard is only binding on compilers, and forces the resulting executable code to have  certain properties. Nevertheless, it does not bind runtime behavior, which is why we spend so much time on exception handling.

Comment: I would also add that the DLL, not being compiled by the C++ compiler, is also not bound by the rules of C++ about what it may or may not do.  Thus, it is allowed to clean up _it's_ statics whenever it wants.  Even worse, even if it's programmed in C++, DLL's aren't conforming programs since they don't have the `main` entry point.

Comment: @MooingDuck Agreed. It would be *great* if the language definition gave us guarantees about runtime behavior. Then we wouldn't have problems such as http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000014.html (scroll to example of null reference). Everything is on the table when the OS is thrashing due to resource constraints. And the point about main() is a good one.

Answer (score 11):

I'm taking this to be a bit of an open-ended question.

I'd say it's like this: The standard only defines what a *program* is. And a program (a "hosted" one, I should add) is a collection of compiled and linked translation units that has a unique `main` entry point.

A shared library has no such thing, so it doesn't even constitute a "program" in the sense of the standard. It's just a bunch of linked executable code without any sort of "flow". If you use load-time linking, the library becomes part of the program, and all is as expected. But if you use *runtime* linking, the situation is different.

Therefore, you may like to view it like this: global variables in the runtime-linked shared object are essentially dynamic objects which are constructed by the dynamic loader, and which are destroyed when the library is unloaded. The fact that those objects are declared like global objects doesn't change that, since the objects aren't part of a "program" at that point.

Comment: Are you saying that a object declared static in a main executable is different from objects declared static in dynamic link libraries ?

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: Right, **if** the library is linked at runtime. Global variables and local static variables are already fairly special and will cause a lot of "under-the-hood" code. With run-time linking, this becomes essentially dynamic construction (with allocation and construction performed by the loader).

Comment: @KerrekSB nice thinking. I am glad as me too was also thinking the same way. +1

Answer (score 1):

If it does violate the standard, who is the violator?  The C++ compiler cannot be considered the violator (since things are being loaded dynamically via a library call); thus it must the the vendor of the dynamic loading functionality, aka the OS vendor.  Are OS vendors bound by the C++ standard when designing their systems?  That definitely seems to be outside of the scope of the standard.

Comment: Oops, didn't read the existing answers!  @rsj lands in the same place but says it much more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Or for another perspective, consider the library itself to be a separate program providing some sort of service.  When this program is terminated (by whatever means the library is unloaded) then all associated service objects should disappear as well, static or not.

Comment: "_library itself to be a **separate program** providing some sort of service_" seriously?

Comment: Libraries do not necessarily load or unload with the program consuming the features in the library.  It will have its own lifecycle, which would also include the execution of the destructors.  So for the purpose of the standard, why not consider it to be a separate conforming program?  :)

Comment: "_(Libraries) will have its own lifecycle, which would also include the execution of the destructors._" Yes, just like any object on the free-store. "_So for the purpose of the standard, why not consider it to be a separate conforming program?_" because it is not a program. Most important fact: it does not start at `main`, does not even have any equivalent of `main`.

Comment: (...) It shares the memory space with the program that loads it. Sometimes it can freely exchange objects, because the underlying libraries, notably the memory allocator, is only linked once. Sometimes there are many memory allocators, so memory allocated in one DLL cannot be deallocated by another DLL or by the main program, and objects of classes that allocate/deallocate memory (like `string`) cannot be freely exchanged.

Comment: (...) A thread is much closer to a program than an explicitly loaded code object, but I would not ever describe a thread as "another program".

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of the tons and tons of platform-specific "extensions" (for a target compiler, architecture, OS, etc) that are available. All of which "violate" the standard in all sorts of ways. But there is only one expected consequence for deviating from standard C++: you aren't portable anymore. (Unless you do a lot of #ifdef or something, but still, that particular code is locked in to that platform).

Since there is currently no standard/cross-platform notion of libraries, if you want the feature, you have to either not use it or re-implement it per-platform. Since similar things are appearing on most platforms, maybe the standard will one day find a clean way to abstract them so that the standard covers them. The advantage will be a cross-platform solution and it will simplify cross platform code.

Comment: "_All of which "violate" the standard in all sorts of ways._" actually they don't violate or "violate" the standard, as the standard says nothing about the behaviour of unloading shared objects.

Comment: they violate ANSI strict compilation, which means the standard no longer guarantees you are portable. The standard doesn't mention shared objects at all.

Comment: No, they do not **violate the ISO standard**. The ISO standard simply does not apply here. The **programmer** stepped outside of the domain of the ISO standard by using `dlopen` and `dlclose`.