# How does C differ from Java's compilation model?

Tags: java, c++, c

What the differences between classical compilation model (C, C++, etc.) and the Java compilation model?

Comment: what?  you mean the difference between compiling to machine code vs compiling to jvm bytecode?  elaborate.

Comment: Is this homework? It looks as though you've stopped in the middle of your sentence, and starting typing a new one, i.e. copied from a question list.

Comment: There is nothing "classical" about C compilation model. Unless you mean actual compiler internals, but then it's basically the same thing everywhere.

Comment: no I didn't take C or C++. The only thing I know about Java is that it does work on every kind of machine on earth. not like C or C++. But I'm not sure if this is the only difference.

Comment: Java compiles to machine code just like C/C++, however the machine its targeting is a virtual machine which is itself a piece of SW which executes the generated code.  So think of it as just targeting a different sort of machine, one that doesn't happen to exist in hardware but which is run via software.

Comment: ... Nothing like a worthless educational class/book to introduce words never used in the industry just to turn a profit on students listening to muck in a classroom, instead of teaching them useful stuff.... like what not to do.

Comment: define terms "classical compilation model" and "Java compilation model"

Comment: @iMohammad: you got it backwards. C is the backbone of programming, used on *every* machine to provide the fundamentals. Java is only available on a small subset of computers.

Comment: Good question. Idk why someone would downvote it

Comment: They taught us that classical compilation model are like C/C++ but looks like no one understand what does it mean. Actually me neither

Comment: @iMohammad:  Java actually does not run on "every kind of machine on Earth."  In order for Java to run on a particular platform, there needs to be a Virtual Machine written for that platform, or a Java compiler capable of creating machine code from Java byte code for that platform.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A proper answer to your question could take several hundred pages to answer, but I'll try to sum it up in a few paragraphs.

Basically, the "classic compilation model" you refer to takes as input human-written source code and emits machine code, which can be loaded and run without further translation of the machine code.  One ramification of this is that the resulting machine code can only be run on compatible hardware and can only be run within a compatible operating system.

The Java compilation model takes human-written source code as input and emits not machine code, but so-called "[byte code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode)".  Byte code cannot be directly executed on a machine.  Instead, it needs to be translated once again by another compiler to machine code, or interpreted on-the-fly by a device that executes instructions on the machine that correspond to the instructions in the byte code.  The latter device is often referred to as a Virtual Machine.  One ramification of this model is that the byte code can be "run" on any platform that has either a byte code compiler or virtual machine written for it.  This gives Java the appearance and effect of complete portability, where there is no such portability implied by the machine code emitted by a C++ compiler stack.

Comment: How wise of you not to discuss any performance effects of byte code vs. machine code compilation ;)

Comment: @larsmans:  Yeah, I definitely did not want to go down that road. :)

Comment: No!, you must provide all several hundred pages! Imaginary -1.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but isn't the emission of byte code just a choice/implementation of a particular compiler? Aren't there Java compilers that emit native code? Isn't there more to the compilation model that just what comes out the other end? I'm thinking of declaration/definition and such.

Comment: My understanding is that all Java compilers emit byte code.  However it is also possible to configure many Java compilers to also take the next step and "compile down" to the platform as well -- but the common denominator is the byte code.

Comment: @JohnDibling Not really. There are some special tools that generate machine code, but those are rarely used. The usual java compilers (javac, eclipse,..) can't generate anything other than bytecode and aren't very sophisticated at all. Also since the result of those java->native compilers isn't a valid java program afterwards, I'm not sure "java compiler" really fits. Hmm.

Comment: There are such compilers, don't know if they're all obsolete, and there were also chips to run bytecode on hardware, which are also obsolete. The fad is over and the language still retains a huge niche, but Sun explored every avenue.

Comment: @Doug Formally, I think that there is no necessary relationship between the language and the compilation model.  Practically, however, there are aspects of Java which imply some sort of dynamic interpretation, and there are aspects of C++ which make this difficult (although mixed models are possible, and the best C++ compilers don't use what I would consider the "classical" model, since they don't generate the final machine code until the link step).

Comment: My god! all these participation in my Question! @JohnDibling I talked to my Instructor about your Answer, he said that you're completely right. But my question is now, ByteCode compiler is it only for Java? Paradon me, I'm still an Intermediate Java Programmer and I started to read about how Java really works and about JVM and these stuff

Comment: @iMohammad:  Java is not the only language that utilizes a compilation model that results in Byte Code and employs virtual machines.  All the .NET languages use a very similar technique.  Conversely, C++ is not the only language that compiles directly to machine code.  FORTRAN is another. (gah!  did I just date myself?)

Comment: @JohnDibling these are so informative answers/replies you have shared thanks! . So, if there is no JVM installed on a machine, java simply will not be compiled to ByteCode? am I getting this right? another thing, you mentioned `One ramification of this is that the resulting machine code can only be run on compatible hardware and can only be run within a compatible operating system.` it's not really clear for me, can you elaborate in a simple way?

Comment: The Java compiler emits Byte Code.  If there is no JVM on the machine where you intend to run this Byte Code, it won't run.

Comment: A C++ program compiled for a Windows machine will not run on a Linux machine.  In order to run your C++ program on a Linux machine, it needs to be compiled by a Linux-compatible compiler -- usually gcc.

Answer (score 8):

Two aspects play into the C (and C++) compilation model. One is its longer history than Java, meaning that it caters to very low-powered compilers and machines. The second is the compilation *target*, which is usually low-level machine code.

To target low-memory compiler environments, C code must be readable from top to bottom, with no backtracking. This means that you have to follow a strict discipline for the order of declarations. (C++ relaxes this a little bit for class definitions.) Further more, each source file must be compilable as an independent *translation unit* which need not know anything about other source files.

Second, because C targets low-level machine code, this means that each translation unit contains essentially *no* metadata, in stark contrast to Java class files. This necessitates a stronger coding discipline in which each translation unit must be provided with the necessary declarations. The compiler cannot just scan all the other files in order to get the required information; it is up to the user to supply it. (C++ enforces this more rigidly, in C you can get away with nasty errors by forgetting a declaration.)

Bear in mind that a C program has to be fully compiled and linked at compile time, so a lot of information has to be available already at that point. Java programs can load classes at runtime, and Java execution generally performs more "fitting" operations (casting, essentially, as opposed to static linking in C) at runtime. The more sophisticated runtime environment of Java allows for a more flexible and modular compilation model.

Comment: I think this response adds valuable input.

Comment: "Bear in mind that a C program has to be fully compiled and linked at compile time" Not absolutely true, since we can do loading at runtime in C/C++ as well. Also clang shows that you can work around some of the mentioned limitations, but it's probably save to assume "classical compilation" really means the conventional approach. +1 still, good summary - if we wanted to cover everything possible here that'd take way too much space.

Comment: @Voo: well, it's of course possible to write an entirely different compiler that has a different compilation model. That said, the C standard does mandate quite a bit of the behaviour I describe. Runtime linking doesn't really matter for the discussion, I'd say, as it isn't related to the compilation model. (E.g. see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002678/do-dynamic-libraries-break-c-standard/8002821#8002821).)

Comment: @Kerrek Fair enough, this gets into a rather esoteric area but I see your point.

Comment: @Voo: Another way to see why dynamic linking is not pertinent: DL is an opaque library-provided service that you invoke explicitly. It's not transparent. The only things that matter for the compilation model are the different ways in which a compiler can take *the same piece of source code* and produce a running program (e.g. compile-time vs load-time linking).

Comment: @James: In the object files? I don't know. I though COFF was an executable format only...

Answer (score 1):

I am going to be brave and compare performance. ;)

The Java compiler `javac` does little optimisation preferring to syntax check code. It does all the reasonable checks required to ensure it will run on a JVM, and some constant evaluation and that's about it.

Most of the smart compilation is done by the JIT which can perform dynamic complication based on how the program is used.  This allows it to inline "virtual" methods, for example, even if the caller and callee are in different libraries.

The C/C++ compiler performs significant static analysis up front.  This means a program will run at almost full speed right from the start.  The CPU performs some dynamic optimisation with instruction re-ordering and branch prediction.  While C/C++ lacks dynamic optimisation, it gains from by making low level access to the system **much** easier. (Its usually not impossible in Java, but low level operations which are trivial in C/C++ can be complex and obscure in Java) It also provides more ways to do the same thing allowing you to choose the optimal solution to your problem.

When Java is likely to be faster.

- If your style of programming suits Java and you only use the sort of features Java supports, Java is likely to be marginally faster (due to dynamic compilation) i.e. you wouldn't use C/C++ to their full potential anyway.
- If your code contains lots of dead code (possibly only known to be dead at run time) Java does a good job at eliminating this. (IMHO A high percentage of micro-benchmarks which suggest Java is faster than C++ are of this type)
- You have a very limited time and/or resources to implement your application. (In which case an even higher level language might be better) i.e. You don't have time to optimise your code much and you need to write safe abstracted code.

When C/C++ is likely to be faster.

- If you use most of the functionality C/C++ provides. Something more advanced programmers tend to do.
- If startup time matters.
- If you need to be creative about algorithms or data structures.
- If you can exploit a low level hardware feature, like direct access to devices.

Answer (score 0):

For short, "classical" compilation (which is a temp term provided by the material because they don't have a real word for it), is basically compiling against a real device (in our case a machine with a physical processor). Instead, Java compiles to code against a virtual device, which is software installed on a machine. The virtual device is what changes and targets the real machine.

In this way your hardware is abstracted. This is why Java can work on "any" machine.

Comment: I'm not sure any of these answers actually address the compilation **model** -- we're all talking about what the compilers emit. Surely by model, we're also referring to the process by which emission occurs, such as the difference in compilation units? Not to mention that a certain Java compiler can emit machine code if it wants.

Comment: @Doug I'm certain the material that he collected this question from (by referring to "classical vs. Java" is exactly concerned with machine vs. virtual code. The fact that you pointed out that a Java compiler can emit machine code, pretty much validates my point.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two kinds of magic. *Machine* magic is only understood by certain wizards. *JVM Bytecode* magic is understood by a special kind of wizard that you have to hire in order to make the machine wizard able to cast spells that make your computer do things. C and C++ compilers generally emit the *machine* kind, whereas Java compilers emit *JVM Bytecode*.

Comment: -1 For targeting idiots. You inadvertently targeted less people by using references to stuff some people won't know about.

Comment: I was trying to add some fun to everyone's Monday morning. I'm sorry that I offended you. I will up your answer as a penance for my sins against SeriousBusiness(tm)

Comment: Didn't offend me. It just doesn't need to be anywhere near the top. I wish I could neg vote without affected your rep. Now that a proper answer has 6 votes

Comment: Edit and I'll undo if it'll let me.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ gets compiled before execution.

Java gets compiled while executing.

Of course, neither language mandates a certain way of being compiled.

Comment: I believe that the statement "Java gets compiled while executed" is not strictly true.  Can Java not be compiled all the way down to the platform?

Comment: @JohnDibling See 3rd sentence. I don't think languages should be tied to compilation methods and so I generalized the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Both convert source code that a human understands, to a machine code that some machine understands. In Java's case it targets a virtual machine, i.e. a program instead of a piece of silicon.

Of course there's nothing to prevent a piece of silicon from understanding JVM byte code (in which case you could rename it from 'byte code' to 'machine code'). And conversely, there's nothing to prevent a compiler from converting C/C++ code to JVM byte code.

Both have a runtime and both require you to tell it which parts of the runtime you intend to use.

I really think you intended to ask a different question.